# openssl logs showing keyblock length of only 88 bytes instead of 136 bytes

Tags: encryption, aes, diffie-hellman, tls, openssl

I was decrypting TLS encrypted data from wireshark using the openssl(TLS1.0 version) TLS logs which provides the complete key block which of size 136 bytes.Now i moved to TLS(1.2 version) in that Key block size is of 88 bytes only.Anybody please help me in this... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry, your question is missing detail. Are you asking why the key block is now shorter? Or why wireshark is reporting a wrong size? Or something else?

Comment: According to RFC the keyblock should be 128 bytes..I am using openssl logs to see the keyblock...My question is it is of the wrong size...